# What type of security sensors should be used in a three bedroom house?

Tags: security

I have just purchased a house and am hoping to install SimpliSafe throughout. I have 3 bedrooms: mine, my children's,  and my office. Would window sensors be best in all these rooms, and then motion detectors in the kitchen and living room? Are motion sensors a good idea if you expect not to be moving about at night? I was think door and window sensors instead on my 9 openings. Is this overkill? I was also thinking one window break sensor.

Comment: There is a very big difference between alarm system that are designed for protecting you while at home (and asleep) and one designed to protect your home while away.  Stay modes try to address this, but for home protection while at home, perimeter sensors are essential.   It is of very little use (at least where I live) to activate the alarm if someone is already inside your house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, motion sensors will be the most effective. However -

- Try not to have the sensor point into possible "Billowing" curtains or directly outside.
- Try not to get sensors to point at each other.
- Consider pet friendly sensors inside the house.

The number of sensors installed would be a factor of the access possibilities from the three rooms; generally, you could detect movement over the two doors of adjoining rooms - if you are comfortable with that, you do not need to monitor inside those rooms.

I am a fan of window magnets (sensors), since they are relatively inexpensive; however, you will either need to bypass them or have the windows closed when activating the alarm. A work-around here is to put certain windows which you know you like to keep open on the same circuit and install a manual bypass toggle switch which will de-link those specific windows from the circuit (the location of the switch must be secret/hidden). That way you can still activate your bypassed alarm and include the closed windows onto the alarm.

One *Glass Break Detector* is only really effective in about a 5m radius, and they can be sensitive - but yes, they are definitely effective when setup correctly.

One thing to consider is to install an outside PIR which can alert you before someone gets into the house. This at least can be activated when you are in the house.

Also, if you have a trap-door, don't forget to put a window magnet there (if your house has tiles which can be easily lifted).

Comment: I feel like monitoring inside my daughters room and my office would be important, hence me thinking about going with window sensors there.

I feel like we would only need motion detectors when we are out of the house, because we'll more than likely set it off at night.

I think a 5m range is good for a glass break detector. We only have a 1200 ft2 house, so that's probably more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

Alarms like the SimpliSafe support "away" mode and "home" mode. In home mode the motion sensors are inactive.  The need for window sensors has a lot to do with how hard it is to reach the window from outside.